# Scroll to a button with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a webscraping script for a school project. I have to scroll down to a button to click, but I can't make it work.

I tried the following code:

```
driver.get('https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28187.The_Lightning_Thief');

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/button')))
button.click()
time.sleep(5)

element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"Button Button--transparent Button--small")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '''//*[@id="ReviewsSection"]/div[5]/div/div[4]/a''')))
button.click()
```

I recieved the following error:
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".Button Button--transparent Button--small"}

I also tried this, but it didn't work either:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

When you scroll down on this page it will load in more reviews, so I guess that the button in the bottom I want to click don't load in, so I also tried to scroll down a few times and then try to scroll to the element, but it didn't work.
Can someone please help out?

EDITED:
I also tried this code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13335037-divergent');

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/button')))
button.click()

time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(3)

element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.Divider.Divider--contents.Divider--largeMargin")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '''//*[@id="ReviewsSection"]/div[5]/div/div[4]/a''')))
button.click()
```

This will scroll down to the bottom once end let the remaining reviews load in, then get the element and scroll again. But it's not scrolling down enough so the See all reviews and ratings won't be in view and can't be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is invalid since you're trying to pass multiple class names to search by class. You need to pass single `@class` only or to use another locator type, e.g.

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".Button.Button--transparent.Button--small")
```

P.S. Note that there are 4 elements with the same set of class names (`"Button Button--transparent Button--small"`), so search by class names is not a good option in this case

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[.="See all reviews and ratings"]')
```

Comment: Hello! First of all, thank you for your answer! I changed the selector to what you recommended and it turned out that at the beginning of the page there is a button with the same selector. I changed the selector to the div that contains the button, but it still gives the same error message.

Comment: @Regcsuu which button you're searching for?

Comment: The see all reviews and ratings button at the end off the reviews.

Comment: @Regcsuu try `element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[.="See all reviews and ratings"]')`

Comment: I tried, but it's not working. I scrolled higher and the button is still not clickable. I even tried using driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,1000)", "") after and the button comes into view, but at the very bottom of the page and not clickable.